# Rack MiniProfiler not capturing sql queries in My Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, rack-mini-profiler

In our Project we have a lot of `ActiveRecord` `models`, we use `Postgres` as our DB Server and also `MongoDB` with `mongoid 2.2` gem. I need to improve/optimize our project to reduce the number of SQL queries being executed I chose `rack-mini-profiler` gem to profile my app for SQL queries.
initially I did

```
gem "rack-mini-profiler"
```

but didn't work giving the following error

> uninitialized constant Mongo::Server (NameError)

then I just fixed the version to `0.9.7` and it worked without any problem, but the sql queries in log were Zero to Minimal. The queries I am trying to profile are of `Postgres` and I can see them in the my terminal, but not in miniprofiler on my view page.

only when user sign_ins/sign_outs the update query shows up some times and nothing else shows up.

I used the same gem with in my friends application and it works out of the box. he's also using 'pg' but uses `ruby-2.1.5` and `rails-4.2.x`

I also tried `?pp=full-backtrace` with no use.

I also have caching enabled via `Dalli` gem and `memcached` and I also tried setting `miniprofiler` store to `MemStore`.

[image: miniprofiler log]

- Ruby: 1.9.3p550
- Rails: 3.1.10
- pg: 0.11.0
- mongoid: 2.2
- OS: Ubuntu 14.04 x86_64

Comment: @SamSaffron have your got any idea what might be wrong?